# Is it possible to "Show all filename extensions" except ".app" on OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

I like to see my filename extensions, but i find the ".app" at the end of every application to be a bit of overkill. Any way to enable them all except that one?

Still an issue in Lion. Was wondering if anyone had anything to add to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but there is a project called [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) which allows you to modify cocoa apps to your liking.  There is also a project which uses SIMBL called [totalfinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com), which doesn't do what you want but is nevertheless a wonderful tool for finder.  Im sure though, if you were motivated enough, you could write a SIMBL plugin that would do what you wanted.

Comment: Can't mark this as the answer, since it doesn't do what the question is about, but I gave you +1 for pointing me toward a really cool utility!